# Spring Boot: ReactiveCrudRepository is not being implemented by any bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra, spring-webflux

I plan to use Cassandra to save data reactively. To do that, I wrote the following interface:

```
@Repository
public interface ContributorStatRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<ContributorStat, Long> {
    Flux<ContributorStat> findByAkonId(String akonId);
}
```

The exception above is thrown:

```
com.example.sample.controller.ContributorStatControllerTest > shouldReturnBadRequestWithBlankContributorStat FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
```

**Do you know why the appropiate bean for `ContributorStatRepository` is not being created?**

I am using Spring boot 2.0.0.M7 and these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
}
```

**Updated**:
Running test:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnBadRequestWithBlankContributorStat() throws Exception {
    requestPayload = mapper.writeValueAsString(new ContributorStatDTO());

    this.mockMvc.perform(post(CONTRIBUTOR_STATS_ROUTE)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(requestPayload)).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
}
```

Comment: could you provide more information? Your repository interface looks strange (declaring two times the extended interface?) and you're not showing the test class that you're running. Also, why adding spring-data-jpa in the mix?

Comment: @BrianClozel Oh I forgot to remove a commented line. Just updated it. Thanks for the observation. Included spring-data-jpa to create another repository that is not reactive. I included the test, but actually all the tests fail, since none bean is found for that repository.

Comment: @Jovanny Did you add `@Enable*Repositories` anywhere? E.g. like [this example](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/28/going-reactive-with-spring-data#reactive-configuration)?

Comment: @Brian, yeah, I have a configuration class which is marked with `@Configuration` and `@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using an `@WebMvcTest` annotated class to test this case (I'm not sure though, that part is missing from your question).

To test Spring WebFlux applications, you should use `@WebFluxTest` (see [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-webflux-tests)). Even if you do, the `ContributorStatRepository` bean won't be there since the web test slice will only consider the web parts of your application and you usually need to mock this one with `@MockBean`.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve that:

1. Check if interface ClientRepository has @Repository annotation
2. Check @EnableJpaRepositories
3. Use

   @MockBean
   private ContributorStatRepository interface;

This case is when you're not going to implement the interface in a concrete class implementation.

Enjoy